# Plone 4.0.5 unified installer failing on Ubuntu 11.04 (natty) with zip/zlib error

Tags: python, ubuntu, plone, zlib

I am a Plone newbie and am trying to install Plone 4.0.5 on Ubuntu 11.04 Natty using the Unified Installer.

I unpack the installer and run the `./install.sh zeo` as root and I get the following error:

```
ZEO Cluster Install selected

Detailed installation log being written to /tmp/Plone-4.0.5-UnifiedInstaller/install.log

Root install method chosen. Will install for use by system user plone

Installing Plone 4.0.5 at /usr/local/Plone

User 'plone' already exists. No need to create it.
Skipping libjpeg build
Skipping zlib build
Skipping readline build
Installing Python 2.6.6. This takes a while...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
LookupError: unknown encoding: zip
Python zlib support is missing; something went wrong in the zlib or python build.

Installation has failed.
See the detailed installation log at /tmp/Plone-4.0.5-UnifiedInstaller/install.log
to determine the cause.
```

I have installed these ubuntu packages too:

```
apt-get install zlib1g zlib1g-dev zlibc libghc6-zlib-dev zlibc
```

The install.log is quite big - I'm just including mentions of zlib here:

```
Starting at Tue May 17 14:12:46 SAST 2011
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-readline, --with-zlib, --disable-tk, --with-cxx
...
Failed to find the necessary bits to build these modules:
_bsddb             _sqlite3           _tkinter        
bsddb185           dbm                gdbm            
sunaudiodev        zlib                               
To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name.


Failed to build these modules:
crypt              nis          
...
```

I can't find a setup.py in the installation files.

Any ideas what I should do or what I should be looking for?

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Its an issue with the Python disutils and the new multilib setup of natty.  I ran into the same issue trying to get sqlite support in Python built from source.

You can hack around it in the detect modules section of the setup.py

http://bugs.python.org/issue9762

**Edit:**

To work around it, change `lib_dirs` in the python setup.py (around line 408) to this (for an x86_64 machine):

```
lib_dirs = self.compiler.library_dirs + [
    '/lib64', '/usr/lib64',
    '/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu',
    ]
```

(the /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu is missing)

Comment: Thank you tMC - solved - I will post steps for other newbies having this problem.

Comment: Thanks for that answer, I've been struggling for weeks now! Note for lazy people in 32 bit systems, the directory is: `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu` instead of the x86_64..

Answer (score 2):

Thank you - Plone installed successfully.

Following [this](http://bugs.python.org/issue9762) and [this](http://bugs.python.org/issue11715) led me to [this patch for setup.py](http://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/7582a78f573b)

For sake of other newbies - here is how to apply the patch:

View the [raw text of the patch here](http://hg.python.org/cpython/raw-rev/7582a78f573b)
and copy from the line immediately following (not including) the `diff...` line to the end. Copy into a text file. For this example let's say you named this file `/tmp/patch.txt`

Change to the root directory of the unpacked Unified Installer files and then do the following:

```
cd packages
tar xjf Python-2.6.6.tar.bz2
rm Python-2.6.6.tar.bz2
cd Python-2.6.6
patch < /tmp/patch.txt
```

If the patch worked you should see:

```
patching file setup.py
Hunk #1 succeeded at 354 (offset 15 lines).
```

Then you need to tar and bzip2 the Python package up again:

```
cd ..
tar cjf Python-2.6.6.tar.bz2 Python-2.6.6
rm -r Python-2.6.6
```

Now run the installer again and it should be able to find the modules it needs to build the python2.6 included in the Unified Installer.

Answer (score 2):

Instructing the Unified Installer to build its own zlib works: `./install.sh --libz=yes zeo`

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you have an acceptable Python on your system already (or can install one), you may use "--with-python=/path/to/Python-2.6" on the install.sh command line.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me - but then I built it on a maverick system, *then* upgraded to natty.

Prereqs that I have that look necessary for you:

```
zlib1g-dev (which you have)
python-gdbm
libgdbm3
libsqlite3-0 (hard to imagine you would not have that)
python-tk
```

bsddb & sunaudio are both part of the system python2.6 - you could try building with that (`aptitude install python2.6`, if necessary)

Comment: I dont believe maverick had a multilib setup- with the arch tuple in the lib path. You can test by downloading the python 2.7.1 source and see if it will compile with all the modules you have the development files for.

Comment: @tMC afaik, Plone requires 2.6 not 2.7 - but the unified installer _includes_ Python2.6 anyway and nickyspag's install method would have used the Plone-included python.

Comment: @auspex python2.6 is going to be just as un-aware of the multilib paths as python 2.7.  Find the setup.py in the included version of python, edit it to include the correct paths and try again.

Comment: @tMC I see your point, but if he just uses the system python2.6, he doesn't need to compile python at all

Comment: Look at his output `Failed to find the necessary bits to build these modules:
_bsddb             _sqlite3           _tkinter        
bsddb185           dbm                gdbm            
sunaudiodev        zlib                               
To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name.` a version of python is trying to build. it mentions the setup.py in the output

Comment: @tMC I understand that - nevertheless, he doesn't _have_ to build Python - it will happily use the system python if he uses: `--with-python=/fullpathtopython2.6`

Comment: I don't know plone installation options. The error he posted is related to build python on a multilib system.

Comment: @tMC No doubt - that's why Plone doesn't _need_ to build python.  Fixing one setup.py file with an Ubuntu specific patch doesn't help in the long run - especially since Python2.6 is apparently not going to be fixed - so the next release of Plone will have the same problem.